# How to trigger an event on ImageCapture?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-imageview, android-camera-intent

I am developing a app in which i have a "start" button on the home screen as soon as I click the button ,camera activity has to start .Now the problem is once i capture the image, i need to trigger a event, which would process the captured image and show the result on that screen itself . How to trigger such an event and display the result ?

Answer (score 0):

You should start the camera activity using `startActivityForResult`, as like following code

```
    File file = new File(_path);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Once the photo taken it will call the callback method written in your activity, the callback method is

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (resultCode) {
    case 0:
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "User cancelled");
        break;

    case -1:
        // show the result here.
        break;
    }
}
```